# jQuery custom content scroller not working on Bootstrap Table responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[jQuery custom content scroller plugin](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) doesn't work with bootstrap table responsive. If I use axis:x or axis:y then it does work. But on mobile responsive the bootstrap table responsive only works either for x axis or y-axis, but not for both the axis (axis:"yx"), Any one can help

[http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)

```
$(".content").mCustomScrollbar({
  axis:"yx" // vertical and horizontal scrollbar
});
```

Comment: Try slimScroll http://plnkr.co/edit/IHnFAiVh0gfcmBdy05Mt?p=preview

Comment: Thank you but I am working with bootstrap 3, so jQuery custom content scroller plugin not working with table-responsive class,

Comment: Bootstrap Responsive Tables make use of overflow-y: hidden, you may need to set overflow to scroll. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive

Comment: #reinder Thank you so much, I have solved this problem,
$(".content").mCustomScrollbar({
    axis:"yx", // vertical and horizontal scrollbar
    theme:"dark"
});
I have just remove (theme:"dark") and its working, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to use jquery or something you can try the following for responsive tables in bootstrap

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <!-- write code -->
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```